# Как скачать изображения из множества ссылок и каждой дать свой название?

Tags: javascript, download

У меня большое количество ссылок с изображением, мне нужно их скачать. Но не просто скачать, а каждой дать название. Я написал код:

```
const superagent = require('superagent');
const fs = require('fs')
superagent.get('http://prntscr.com/qmm7xh').end((e,r) => { fs.writeFile('./test.png',r.body,err => {if(err) console.log(err)}) })
```

Но у меня есть excel таблица в которой столбцы: ссылка , название. А мне нужно эти ссылки скачать с этим названием. Возможно через объект или как-то ещё.
У меня это выглядит так:
 Двигатель Насос вакуумный - http://backup.bamper.by/unzip/4496/zchbu/9fa64b290a2333e2ec3f08f03d15a0ff.jpg
 Генератор - http://backup.bamper.by/unzip/4496/zchbu/c2c8f57b9d506166d72427ad3e937032.jpg,http://backup.bamper.by/unzip/4496/zchbu/75504765155af61a7b0344b25ea5149b.jpg
Фара противотуманная левая  - http://backup.bamper.by/unzip/4496/zchbu/db578cc6be27ed463c3fe80bdbf62c1b.jpg,http://backup.bamper.by/unzip/4496/zchbu/3973ca705f33df0fed1bc039b2d7cb85.jpg
 и т.д
И мне нужно так их и скачать

Answer (score 0):

Переведите из XSLX в [CSV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV), прям открыв и пересохранив в самом excel и скачайте!

```
const csv = `
First link;http://backup.bamper.by/unzip/4496/zchbu/db578cc6be27ed463c3fe80bdbf62c1b.jpg
Second link;http://backup.bamper.by/unzip/4496/zchbu/db578cc6be27ed463c3fe80bdbf62c1b.jpg
Third link;http://backup.bamper.by/unzip/4496/zchbu/db578cc6be27ed463c3fe80bdbf62c1b.jpg
`;
csv.split("\n").map((line)=>line.split(";")[1]).forEach((url)=>console.log(url));
```